# Error: [delete] URI Pattern while sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm installing devise on my existing rails app.
And I met some problem in sign out.

view:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       users/sessions#new
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       users/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) users/sessions#destroy
```

As you can see above 'sign_out' must be [delete].
But when i sing out the website I met follow error.

```
Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

And I don't understand why [delete] changes to [GET]

Update: application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree .
```

Update:
One more thing I want to say is that this app is built with angularJS.
So jquery files are stored in vendor/assets/stylesheets/bower_components/jquery.
And I used below two answers. But I still met above error.

Comment: Can you post your `application.js`?

Comment: I added application.js.

Comment: One more thing I want to say is that this app is built with angularJS.
So jquery files are stored in vendor/assets/stylesheets/bower_components/jquery.

And I used below two answers. But I still met above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) in order to send `delete` requests by using `<%= link_to ..., method: :delete %>`.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree .
```

Browsers only send GET requests in response to a link being clicked. So what [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) does is adds an event handler to elements with the `data-method` attribute which creates a form and sends it. This creates a POST request with a special `_method` param that the Rack::MethodOverride middleware picks up on and changes the request method to `DELETE`.

You can also use [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which creates an actual form and does not rely on javascript:

```
<%= button_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have jquery-rails installed in your app. That is why  the `DELETE` request is precessed as `GET`. Try the below

Include `gem 'jquery-rails'` in `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`. Later add

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require_tree .
```